# Included font does not load from resource dictionary in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, app.xaml

In my WPF application, I included the font that I'm using in `App.xaml` file  as following:

```
<Application x:Class="STFAPP.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:STFAPP"
         StartupUri="Views/LoginWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <!--Included Fonts-->
        <FontFamily x:Key="TheSans">pack://application:,,,/Style/Fonts/#TheSans</FontFamily>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Style/TextBlock.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

The `TextBlock.xaml` is a resource dictionary that include the `TextBlock` style:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="TitleStyle">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource TheSans}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
</Style>
```

I used the style in my `TextBlock` as following:

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello" Style="{StaticResource TitleStyle}"/>
```

The font is not loaded !?

If I avoid using separated resource dictionary (`TextBlock.xaml` file) and paste the style direct to `App.xaml`, the font will loaded successfully:

```
<Application x:Class="STFAPP.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:STFAPP"
         StartupUri="Views/LoginWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <!--Included Fonts-->
        <FontFamily x:Key="TheSans">pack://application:,,,/Style/Fonts/#TheSans</FontFamily>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="TitleStyle">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource TheSans}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
        </Style>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I want to separated the styles in multiple resources dictionary files to organize my application files.

I would be grateful for any help

Comment: Did you try to define FontFamily within the TextBlock.xaml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to `DynamicResource` in the `Style`:

```
 <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource TheSans}" />
```

Or move the `FontFamily` resource to `TextBlock.xaml` or another resource dictionary, like for example `Fonts.xaml`, and also merge this one:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Style/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Style/TextBlock.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Changed to DynamicResource solved my issues. Thank you